# Show (p ∧ q) → q ≡ T by using table 6 and the first line of table 7

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I used the left side to attempt to prove it was T.
[Chart of Laws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqeFY.png)

(p ∧ q) → q ≡ T

(p ∧ q) → q

**Using the first line in table 7**

¬(p ∧ q) v q

**D'Morgans Law**

(¬p  v ¬q) v q

**Associative Law**

¬p     v (¬q  v q)

**Negation Law**

¬p     v T

**Domination Law**

T ≡ T

I was wondering if this is right since I felt that you can't do that with domination law. If anyone could double check thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's fine ... the $p$'s, $q$'s and $r$'s in these laws can be *any* statement

Comment: Only one little error, it's De Morgan, not D'Morgan

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's completely correct.

The domination law states that $q \lor T$ is always true for any statement $q$. So it's true especially for any negated statement $\neg p \equiv q$.

Another way to think about this is to consider:

$$(\neg p \lor T) \equiv \neg\neg (\neg p \lor T) \equiv \neg(p \land F) \equiv \neg F \equiv T$$

that is using the double negation law and then applying De Morgan's laws one time to use the domination law directly with the $\land$ operator.